# Eureka with AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, amazon-ecs, spring-cloud-netflix

We are using Eureka with AWS ECS service that can scale docker containers.
In ECS if you leave out the host port, or specify it as being '0', in your task definition, then the port will be chosen automatically and reported back to the service. After the task is running, describing it should show what port(s) it bound to.

How does Eureka can resolve what port to use if we have several EC2 instance. For example Service A from EC2-A try to call Service B from EC2-B. So Eureka can resolve hostname , but cannot identify exposed port

Comment: So, Eureka works fine with AWS ESC if we have static Docker port. We just need expose this port then Eureka can resolve AWS host using AmazonInfo (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_using_eureka_on_aws)

But Eureka doesn’t help you if you want to use ECS autoscalling feature.

Actually, we can use Eureka with ECS(autoscalling) and Docker only with Docker network host (docker run --net=host). But this approach is not good. For Kubernetes it’s OK, because each Docker image is isolated in Pod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was resolved
https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues/937

Currently ECS agent knows about running port.

But **I don't recommend to use Eureka with ECS, because Application Load Balancer does the same. It works as service registry and discovery**. You don't need to run addition service(Eureka), ALB is cheap.

Comment: Thats perfectly fine not to use eureka, but what about microservices intercommunications? its very easy with eureka, I can just use Feign client with service name.

Comment: ALB doesn't work for client side resiliency. correct me if it's wrong

Answer (score 5):

Hi @Aleksandr Filichkin,

I don't think Application Load Balancer and service registry does the same. 
The main difference traffic flows over the (application) load balancer whereas the service registry just gives you a healthy endpoint that your client directly can address (so the network traffic does not flow over the service registry).

Cheap is a very relative term, maybe it's cheap for some, maybe it's an unnecessary overhead for others.

Comment: You can add this as a comment and not as an answer. Please read the rules.

Comment: I wish, but I don't have enough stackoverflow point to comment on someone else answer's.

Answer (score 4):

There is another solution.

You can create an application loadbalancer and a target group, in which the docker containers can be launched.

Every docker container has set their hostname to the hostname of the loadbalancer. If you need a pretty url, then you can utilize Route53 for DNS-Routing.

It looks like this:

**Service Discovery with Loadbalancer-Hostname**

[image: Service Discovery with Loadbalancer-Hostname]

**Request Flow**

[image: Request Flow]

If you have two containers of the same task on different hosts, both will communicate the same loadbalancer hostname to eureka.

With this solution you can use eureka with docker on AWS ECS without loosing the advantages and flexibility of dynamic port mapping.